# Parallelizing with OpenMP - how?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallelize an OpenMP raytracing algorithm that contains two for loops.

Is there anything more I can do than just setting `omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads())` and putting `#pragma omp parallel for` in front of the first for loop?

So far I've reached a 2.13-times faster algorithm.

Code:

```
start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for

for (int i = 0; i < (viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin); j++)
    {
        int intersection_object = -1; // none
        int reflected_intersection_object = -1; // none
        double current_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff; // maximum positive double
        double current_reflected_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff; // maximum positive double

        RAY ray, shadow_ray, reflected_ray;
        PIXEL pixel;
        SPHERE_INTERSECTION intersection, current_intersection, shadow_ray_intersection, reflected_ray_intersection, current_reflected_intersection;

        double red, green, blue;
        double theta, reflected_theta;

        bool bShadow = false;

        pixel.i = i;
        pixel.j = j;

        // 1. compute ray:
        compute_ray(&ray, &view_point, &viewport, &pixel, &camera_frame, focal_distance);

        // 2. check if ray hits an object:

        for (int k = 0; k < NSPHERES; k++)
        {
            if (sphere_intersection(&ray, &sphere[k], &intersection))
            {
                // there is an intersection between ray and object
                // 1. Izracunanaj normalu...
                intersection_normal(&sphere[k], &intersection, &ray);
                // 2. ako je lambda presjecista manji od trenutacnog:
                if (intersection.lambda_in < current_lambda)
                {
                    current_lambda = intersection.lambda_in;
                    intersection_object = k;
                    copy_intersection_struct(&current_intersection, &intersection);
                }
                // izracunaj current lambda current_lambda =
                // oznaci koji je trenutacni object : intersection_object = 
                // kopiraj strukturu presjeka : copy_intersection_struct();
            }
        }

        // Compute the color of the pixel:
        if (intersection_object > -1)
        {
            compute_shadow_ray(&shadow_ray, &intersection, &light);
            theta = dotproduct(&(shadow_ray.direction), &(intersection.normal));
            for (int l = 0; l<NSPHERES; l++)
            {
                if (l != intersection_object)
                {
                    if (sphere_intersection(&shadow_ray, &sphere[l], &shadow_ray_intersection) && (theta>0.0))
                        bShadow = true;
                }
            }
            if (bShadow)
            {   // if in shadow, add only ambiental light to the surface color
                red = shadow(sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CRED], ambi_light_intensity);
                green = shadow(sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CGREEN], ambi_light_intensity);
                blue = shadow(sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CBLUE], ambi_light_intensity);
            }
            else
            {
                // the intersection is not in shadow:
                red = blinnphong_shading(&current_intersection, &light, &view_point,
                    sphere[intersection_object].kd_rgb[CRED], sphere[intersection_object].ks_rgb[CRED], sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CRED], sphere[intersection_object].shininess,
                    light_intensity, ambi_light_intensity);
                green = blinnphong_shading(&current_intersection, &light, &view_point,
                    sphere[intersection_object].kd_rgb[CGREEN], sphere[intersection_object].ks_rgb[CGREEN], sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CGREEN], sphere[intersection_object].shininess,
                    light_intensity, ambi_light_intensity);
                blue = blinnphong_shading(&current_intersection, &light, &view_point,
                    sphere[intersection_object].kd_rgb[CBLUE], sphere[intersection_object].ks_rgb[CBLUE], sphere[intersection_object].ka_rgb[CBLUE], sphere[intersection_object].shininess,
                    light_intensity, ambi_light_intensity);
            }
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].red = red;
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].green = green;
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].blue = blue;
            glColor3f(tabelaPixlov[i][j].red, tabelaPixlov[i][j].green, tabelaPixlov[i][j].blue);

            intersection_object = -1;
            bShadow = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // draw the pixel with the background color 
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].red = 0;
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].green = 0;
            tabelaPixlov[i][j].blue = 0;
            intersection_object = -1;
            bShadow = false;
        }
        current_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff;
        current_reflected_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff;
    }

}
//glFlush();
stop = omp_get_wtime();
for (int i = 0; i < (viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin); j++)
    {
        glColor3f(tabelaPixlov[i][j].red, tabelaPixlov[i][j].green, tabelaPixlov[i][j].blue);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(i, j);
        glEnd();

    }
}
printf("%f\n št niti:%d\n", stop - start, omp_get_max_threads());
glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: `omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads())` has no effect at all. Both calls operate on the same OpenMP internal control variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ray tracing you should use `schedule(dynamic)`.  Besides that I would suggest fusing the loop

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) {
for(int n=0; n<((viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin)*(viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin); n++) {
    int i = n/(viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin);
    int j = n%(viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin)
    //...
}
```

Also, why are you setting the number of threads?  Just use the default which should be set to the number of logical cores.  If you have Hyper Threading ray tracing is one of the algorithms that will benefit from Hyper Threading so you don't want to set the number of threads to the number of physical cores.

In addition to using MIMD with OpenMP I would suggest looking into using SIMD for ray tracing.  See Ingo Wald's PhD thesis for an example on how to do this http://www.sci.utah.edu/~wald/PhD/.  Basically you shoot four (eight) rays in one SSE (AVX) register and then go down the ray tree for each ray in parallel.  However, if one ray finishes you hold it and wait until all four are finished (this is similar to what is done on the GPU).  There have been many papers written since which have more advanced tricks based on this idea.

Comment: OpenMP supports loop collapsing since version 3.0. One should also keep in mind that with memory-bound algorithms, if program's data doesn't fit in the CPU cache, vectorised multithreaded codes could perform worse than scalar multithreaded codes.

Comment: @HristoIliev, yes but MSVC does not support OpenMP 3.0 and it's trivial to fuse a loop by hand.  Ray tracing is not normally memory bound.  But even so, it's not trivial to use SIMD with ray tracing so anyone doing it need to know what they are doing.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your answers, and thanks for clearing it out for me a little bit more. I will try your suggestions as soon as I get home.

All the best